# Try and Except with a list and multiple inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a D&D style character generator and I am rolling the stats for them and allowing them to allocate them to the ability score they want. I would like to have the ability to start at the same stat they were at vs the entire section over again.

Here is what I have

```
from random import randint
def char_stats():
    # roll 4 D6s drop the lowest number and add the highest 3
    s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6 = ([],[],[],[],[],[])
    for x in range(4):
        s1.append(randint(1,6))
        s2.append(randint(1,6))
        s3.append(randint(1,6))
        s4.append(randint(1,6))
        s5.append(randint(1,6))
        s6.append(randint(1,6))
    stat1 = sorted(s1)
    stat2 = sorted(s2)
    stat3 = sorted(s3)
    stat4 = sorted(s4)
    stat5 = sorted(s5)
    stat6 = sorted(s6)
    return sum(stat1[1:]),sum(stat2[1:]),sum(stat3[1:]),sum(stat4[1:]),sum(stat5[1:]),sum(stat6[1:])

a = list(char_stats())
print "Please choose one of the following for your stat: {}".format(a)
while len(a) > 0:
    try:
        Strength = int(raw_input('Please input one of these stats for your Strength:\n'))
        if Strength in a:
            a.remove(Strength)
            print a
        Wisdom = int(raw_input('Please input one of these stats for your Wisdom:\n'))
        if Wisdom in a:
            a.remove(Wisdom)
            print a
        Intelligence = int(raw_input('Please input one of these stats for your Intelligence:\n'))
        if Intelligence in a:
            a.remove(Intelligence)
            print a
        Constitution = int(raw_input('Please input one of these stats for your Constitution:\n'))
        if Strength in a:
            a.remove(Constitution)
            print a
        Dexterity = int(raw_input('Please input one of these stats for your Dexterity:\n'))
        if Dexterity in a:
            a.remove(Dexterity)
            print a
        Charisma = int(raw_input('Please input one of these stats for your Charisma:\n'))
        if Charisma in a:
            a.remove(Charisma)
    except ValueError:
        print "Incorrect Input"
        continue
```

I have tried nesting each of the if statements (which I believe is very bad form) and have similar results. I have also tried grouping all the inputs into the try and not the calculations and have gotten the same results.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "loop until valid" logic for both the format (int) of the input, and the value (is it in the list of rolled stats?).  The basic logic is this:

```
while True:
    # get input
    # check input
    # if input is valid,
    #   break
```

In your case, this looks something like

```
while True:
    user = input("Please enter a stat to use")
    if user.isnumeric():
        stat_choice = int(user)
        if stat_choice in a:
            break
```

Now, to make *effective* use of this, you need to parametrize your six stats and put those into a loop:

```
stat_name = ["Strength", "Wisdom", ...]
player_stat = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for stat_num in range(len(player_stat)):
    while True:
        user = input("Please input one of these stats for your" + \
                      stat_name[stat_num] + ": ")
        # Validate input as above

    player_stat[stat_num] = stat_choice
```

Note that you can similarly shorten your **char_stats** routine to a few lines.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: It somewhat gets me moving, I see the logic you are going with and I will play around with it a bit more.

Comment: Great!  Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one function in your code (`char_stats`) so I feel like you know how to do functions.

This is a great place to use a function.

My suggestion, for this code, would be to write a function that incorporates the try/except, the asking of the question, and the checking against the stats list.

Something like this:

```
def pick_a_stat(stats, prompt):
    """Prompt the user to pick one of the values in the `stats` list,
    and return the chosen value. Keep prompting until a valid entry
    is made.
    """

    pass  # Your code goes here.
```